# What does it mean to down load the ..common.. driver?

Tags: drivers, printing

[From this paragraph](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Canon/Canon-i-sensys_MF4350d):

> Printer Language: UFRII-LT Driver link is the mfg website download. Two drivers to install. **Install the ..common.. driver first**. Multi-function device: Printer / Scanner / Fax. Scanner work 100% with the pixma back end. See link to a howto. Fax not tested yet.

What do they mean by ..common.. driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They could mean Common Unix Printing System [CUPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS).

> CUPS is the software you use to print
>   from applications like the web browser
>   you are using to read this page. It
>   converts the page descriptions
>   produced by your application (put a
>   paragraph here, draw a line there, and
>   so forth) into something your printer
>   can understand and then sends the
>   information to the printer for
>   printing.
>
> Now, since every printer manufacturer
>   does things differently, printing can
>   be very complicated. CUPS does its
>   best to hide this from you and your
>   application so that you can
>   concentrate on printing and less on
>   how to print. Generally, the only time
>   you need to know anything about your
>   printer is when you use it for the
>   first time, and even then CUPS can
>   often figure things out on its own.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/overview.html.

Answer (score 0):

It means exactly what it says. Canon's driver (as with many others) comes in usually two packages, and one has "common" as part of the name.